# how do I properly split this string after the first position (0) so that the one or more characters after 0 are read?

Tags: java, split, playing-cards

Basically I have this code, that with the input of 2 **OR** 3 letters/numbers combos like (AH, 10D, JS, and 7C) read back as value's of suits (Ace of Hearts, 10 of Diamonds, Jack of Spades, 7 of Clubs.)

*Why, if I input "10D", does the code print nothing back? Why is it not register 10? How can I fix this? 
ALSO: Please help me figure out how to shorten the case 2 - case 10 range into something more eloquent? I cannot use if-then-else statements.*

```
System.out.print("Please enter a letter/integer of a playing card (A, J, Q, K, or 2 - 10),\nfollowed by card type (D, H, S, C):");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = kbd.next().toUpperCase();
    String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0, userInput.length() / 2);  // gives first half of string
    String suitofCard = userInput.substring(userInput.length() / 2); //give last half of string with + 1 if odd
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    switch (valueofCard) {
    case "A":
        result.append("Ace of ");
        break;
    case "J":
        result.append("Jack of ");
        break;  
    case "Q":
        result.append("Queen of ");
        break;  
    case "K":
        result.append("King of ");
        break;
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "4":
    case "5":
    case "6":
    case "7":
    case "8":
    case "9":
    case "10":          
        result.append(valueofCard + " of ");
    break;  
        }

    switch (suitofCard) {
    case "D":
        result.append("Diamonds");
        break;  
    case "H":
        result.append("Hearts");
        break;      
    case "S":
        result.append("Spades");
        break;      
    case "C":
        result.append("Clubs");
        break;
        }

    System.out.println(result.toString());

    kbd.close();
```

Comment: As per your explanation the input will be 2 or 3 chars in length, so why not code it like this?

Comment: How do you mean? here is a link to another persons question that states my exact perimeters and maybe (?) explains why I am coding in this format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834840/concatenating-switch-statements-for-playing-cards-assignment

Answer (score 1):

If you use a *regular expression*, it will also reject bad input for you.

Regex: `([AJQK2-9]|10)([DHSC])`

Sample code:

```
String card = "QS"; // Queen of Spades

Pattern cardPattern = Pattern.compile("([AJQK2-9]|10)([DHSC])");

Matcher m = cardPattern.matcher(card);
if (! m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Not a valid card: " + card);
} else {
    String rank = m.group(1);
    String suit = m.group(2);
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that, as an integer, `3 / 2 = 1` so when you input `10D`, the substring reads the position counter as 1 instead of 2 which makes the string 1 instead of 10, which isn't handled by your cases.

I would recommend using either

```
if(userInput.length()>2)
{
    String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0,2);
    String suitofCard = userInput.substring(2);
}
else
{
    String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0,1);
    String suitofCard = userInput.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: I know this is my problem, but it was the simplest solution for the other variables... So I thought by this point I could make a simple code or calculation to help in this one case of 10

Comment: @m bunn Just change it to case of 1 or write some if else statements to decide where to place the end pointed depending on if the user input is 2 or 3 characters long. The simplest way would be to just make it case of 1 instead of case of 10.

Comment: Changing it to case of 1 only returns the "1 of " and no suit. this is not the same as 10 of (suit). Also, it is still misreading, hence no suit, because of the division with the 0 out of "10" being divded on.... please help! That was a great idea to start with ;)

Comment: @m bunn Oh I didn't realize. I don't use cases all that often. See if the code I put in my original post would work for you.

Comment: look at above answer, this makes me use a if-else statement too, unless you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to code to the exceptional case(s)

Like

```
String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0, 1);
// unless starts with "10"
if (userInput.startWith ("10")) {
  valueofCard = userInput.substring(0, 2);     
}
```

Comment: this substring method was hard to accomplish because I can not use if-then-else statements in my program

Comment: Sorry, did not know we were playing soccer but no legs allowed. OK Use a switch statement for length of input

Comment: I agree with you.... Thank you so much either way. I had to turn my assignment in at midnight. I said screw those four cards of 10 haha